# Generic interface error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I have a generic interface:

```
public interface DAO<T>
{
    public T get(long id);
    public Set<T> getAll();
    public void delete(T object); 
    public void update(T object);
    public void create(T object);
}
```

and an implementing class:

```
public class FooDAO implements DAO<Foo>
{
    ... implementations here ...
}
```

Why does eclipse tell me I have the following error:

"The type DAO is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments ".

This doesn't show up in the Problems tab and everything builds and runs just fine, but I still see the error in the editor window. What's going on here?

Comment: Wouldnt be an import problem if the type DAO is recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 3/21/2011, I've tried all of the answers to no effect. The project runs fine, so I'm chalking this up to a bug in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to matt b.  But make sure the eclipse project is fully building.  If there are other files that fail to compile the project as a whole may not build and the changes you made to DAO may not compile (thus be visible).

As is though, your code looks like it should compile.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your workspace is set to Automatically build Projects, perhaps you are viewing an outdated error message?

Sometimes the Editor seems to "lag" behind the true state of the project and still display no-longer-valid errors, try to simple close the open file and re-open it.

Comment: It also wouldn't hurt to clean and rebuild the project. Sometimes that clears out cruft that can cause this.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, try closing Eclipse and reopening it. It likes to glitch out sometimes.